# C# how to bind a datagrid t observableCollection of classes with observable collections using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid which has to be associated to an observable collection of the following class:

```
public class CfgCounters
{
    public int valuePresent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> obcDatetime { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> obcLastExecutedPP { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> obcNumDimsOK { get; set; }
}
```

I have therefore

```
ObservableCollection<CfgCounters> obcCounters = new ObservableCollection<CfgCounters>();
```

which I fill with instances and then associate to the dtg with dtg.ItemsSource = obcCounters;

the result is 
[image]

which obviously is not showing the obcs in any way.
So the question is: how can I in code behind show (in any way would do) those observable collections **using code behind only**?
Thanks

Comment: You have lists but you want to treat them as a single row. For instance obcDatetime...  What are you trying to show to the user?  The first date in the list? Comma separated values of all the dates in the list?  Are you actually wanting to use a RowDetailsTemplate to show the values?

Comment: Yes a csv might be a good option.

Comment: string output = String.Join(",",obcDateTime.Select(x => x.ToShortDateString()).ToArray());  this will stuff the date list into a single csv string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform each `CfgCounters` object into an item with only scalar properties, e.g.:

```
ObservableCollection<CfgCounters> obcCounters = new ObservableCollection<CfgCounters>();
...
dtg.ItemsSource = obcCounters.Select(x => new
{
    x.valuePresent,
    x.Name,
    obcDatetime = string.Join(",", x.obcDatetime.Select(y => y.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))),
    obcLastExecutedPP = string.Join(",", x.obcLastExecutedPP),
    obcNumDimsOK = string.Join(",", x.obcNumDimsOK)
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Know I know the meaning of the expression: "to be taken aback"! I had not thought about that. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is hierarchical and your view is not. You maybe looking for:

1. **[TreeView](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/) to display hierarchical data** as you have.
2. Or you can flatten the data and use this as the source of the datagrid. The code examples show a view model inherited from the data model but a conversion in code behind to a new type would also be possible.
3. Datagrid can also group lists. But this doesn't fit here, see 2.

---

When the csv doesn't change at run time:

```
public class CfgCountersViewModel : CfgCounters
{

    public string obcDatetimeCsv => String.Join(",", obcDatetime);
    ...
}
```

Or when the childs of CfgCounters changes during run time, something more complex like:

```
public class CfgCountersViewModel : CfgCounters, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CfgCountersViewModel() 
    {
         // UpdateObcDatetimeCsv when obcDatetime changes
         obcDatetime.OnCollectionChanged += (sender, args) => 
         {
              obcDatetimeCsv = String.Join(",", obcDatetime);
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for helping. I can't use threeview for I have to stuck the datagrid. Additionally I can add member (like obcDattimeCsv) to the class for that would be a waste (the class can contain a large number of elements). All what I ca do is to operate on the datagrid in order to regenerate columsn. But  I didn't succeed in it :-(